# IMU sensor suddenly outputs only a fixed value

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, imu

### Description of the situation

I am calculating the angle using BMI 160.

Intermittently, the sensor's value is fixed.

I've tested it in certain situations, but each of them happens in a different test situation.

The test method rotated the sensor several times at the same angle as when the sensor failed, but did not occur.

I use the data from the sensor only with **outputData * (9.8 / 16384)** operations.

### My Setting

> OS : Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
>
> IDE : MPLAB X IDE v5.30
>
> Dugger Tool : PICKIT 3
>
> Sensor : Bosch BMI 160
>
> MCU : dsPIC33EV128

### Question

I have two questions.

1. Do these malfunctions occur frequently in IMU sensors?
2. Do you need a separate algorithm to use the sensor?

### Resources

PICkit™ 3 In-Circuit Debugger : https://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails/PG164130

dsPIC33EV 5V CAN-LIN STARTER KIT : https://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails/dm330018

Bosch BMI 160 :
https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/motion-sensors/imus/bmi160.html

Comment: Don't know your particular chip, but we had a problem with other Bosch product, BNO055, which sporadically stops responding to I2C requests. Our solution was to reset the chip when that happens, but starting time up to 700ms means this is not suitable for every application. If we ever have to get rid of this delay we'll probably use cheaper sensor and do fusion in software.

Comment: "1.  these malfunctions occur frequently in IMU sensors?" It's very common yes, IMU are very sensitive to mechanical stress. Can you share what PCB you are using, an eval kit, your own board? How was the IMU mounted? Can you show where it is located on the board and as much detail on this setup as possible?

Comment: @Maple Let's consider how to initialize it.

Comment: @Cisco25 It is a company developed product and PCB made by H / W team, so I don't know the circuit diagram or circuit. I will give your opinion to the H / W team. thank you for the reply.